# Python error (pywintypes.com)

Tags: python, math, com

Do anyone of you know this error?

I get it out of a python script that synchronises some data.
The script crashes randomly and the function that generates this error gives back a number that is always the same. There's not a specific dataset it crashes.

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten.', (0, None, u'In der arithmetischen Operation ist ein \xdcber- oder Unterlauf aufgetreten.', None, 0, -2147024362), None)
```

*Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten* means: Exception occured

*In der arithmetischen Operation ist ein \xdcber- oder Unterlauf aufgetreten* means something like: An \over- or underflow occurred in the arithmetic operation.

Comment: `\xdc` is the Latin-1 codepoint for `Ü`.

Comment: What is your problem here ? Do you not understand what an overflow or underflow is ? Or are you looking for how to debug it ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, guys. Yes, i know what an overflow is :) But i hoped someone knows the error-code.... Finally it came out that the python-code itself wasn't the Problem. We couldn't solve the Problem but found out that it works on most pc's - only on a few ones this script doesn't work. So it's an environmental problem. Problem solved for you :)

Answer (score 0):

In `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x7\Sheets.py` I found this:

> Note that many Office objects do not use zero-based indexing.

so I changed from `wb.Sheets[0].Cells(1,2).Value` to `wb.Sheets[1].Cells(1,2).Value`
and it works without having shown this Error again.